# Download file from /tmp to client in Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to download a file created on an http Google Cloud function saved in the `/tmp` directory. Everything I try throws "Error: could not handle the request".

The file my code generates is saved at `/tmp/output.wav` and I can use `fs.readdirSync('/tmp')` to see the file. But, if I try `res.download('/tmp/output.wav', 'output.wav')` it throws the "Error: could not handle the request".

If I do `res.send( fs.readdirSync('/tmp')[0] );` I can see the file. So I know it's there and readable. Why can't I get it to download to the client?

I checked the logs and there's nothing additional. This code also executes locally on my machine.

I am wondering if this is due to a quota limitation? Would I get a better error if so?

Full code:

```
exports.master = async (req, res ) => {
    const fs = require('fs');

    // Some code to make the file at /tmp/output.wav

    fs.readdirSync('/tmp').forEach(file => {
        console.log(file);
        files.push( file );
    });
    // Code will fire up to this point
    res.download('/tmp/output.wav', 'output.wav');
});
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the [minimal complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the problem.  We should be able to duplicate the issue using what you show.  You might be making a mistake somewhere that we can't see.

Comment: When the file in created in the /tmp?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working on my end:

```
exports.master = async (req, res) => {
    const fs = require('fs')

    // Some code to make the file at /tmp directory
    fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/output.txt','testing output')
    var files = [{}];

    fs.readdirSync('/tmp','utf8').forEach(file => {
        console.log(file);
        files.push(file);
    });

    res.download('/tmp/output.txt','output.txt')
}
```

I believe there's a problem in your async function or creation of files or on your file/s.